# How to pass dictionary and image through ajax to views.py in Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hello I'm sorry because Im new to using django. I'm currently using ajax to send files to my views.py. My dilemma is I need to pass both a dictionary and a formData containing 2 images. How do I pass this to my view, and how do I access the images and the dictionary in my views.py? pls help

The concepts I know so far to transfer data are ajax and FormData. As much as possible I'd like to keep using them for the solution

**jQuery and Ajax**

```
                    const form = new FormData();
                    form.append('tradeimage', extractPhoto(tradeimage));
                    form.append('receiveimage', extractPhoto(receiveimage));

                data = {
                    'tradename': tradename,
                    'receivename': receivename,
                    'description': description
                };
                generateCSRFToken();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/submit_post/',
                    data: form,
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("success")
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("somethings wrong with form")
                    }
                });
```

**views.py**

```
def submit_post(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    return redirect('/marketplace')
post = Post()
if 'tradeimage' and 'receiveimage' in request.FILES:
    post.author = request.user
    post.trade_item = request.FILES.get('tradeimage')
    post.receive_item = request.FILES.get('tradeimage')

#HOW DO I GET DATA FROM DICTIONARY?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the data you are sending to the server is in the variable `form`, not the variable `data`? From the code you provided, the ajax data would only include 'tradeimage' and 'receiveimage'. Did you mean to include 'receiveimage', 'receivename', and 'description' in this? If so, you should append those to `form`.

Anyways, on the server check what is in `request.POST`

Comment: This post could to put as comment.

Comment: @juliansalas. Would if I had the rep to do so.

Comment: hello! I managed to solve my problem. You're somewhat right. I just appended my data to my DataForm then accessed it server side by request.POST.get('tradeitem'). Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Just with the name of 'dictionary'. More better approach would be using JSON. The same approach would be ok with files, only with `request.FILES['name_of_the_picture']`.

Example is here, one variable and then JSON:

```
# your view
def rate_quiz(request):
     if request.is_ajax():
         quiz_id = request.POST.get('quiz_id', False)
         answers = json.loads(request.POST.get('answers', False))


$.ajax({
        url: {% url 'rate_quiz' %},
        type: 'POST',
        'data': {
            'quiz_id': '1',
            'answers': JSON.stringify(getAnswers(questions)), //or just manually created JSON
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        },
        error: function (req, err) {
            console.log('error');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success == true) {
                console.log(result));
            }
        }
    });
```